# New line (line breaking) does not work for \tcbox

Tags: line-breaking, tcolorbox

I put some text into a box using `\tcbox`. I then intend to create a new line in the box as follows:

```
\tcbox{%
        \begin{small}
            \begin{concmath}
                first line\\ % here a new line is expected in the box. 
                second line. \\ \\
            \end{concmath}
        \end{small}\\
    }%
```

But, new line is not created in the box.

**P.S.** `concmath` is used to change the font, as it is need. Font change is defined as follows:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareMathVersion{concmath}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{concmath}{\encodingdefault}{ccr}{m}{n}
\newenvironment{concmath}
{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont\mathversion{concmath}}
{\ignorespacesafterend}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use option `tikznode`. It is documented near the end of [`tcolorbox` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), sec. 4.12. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tcbox[tikznode]{%
  \small
  text \\ text
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update

With

```
\tcbox[tikznode]{%
        \begin{small}
            \begin{concmath}
                first line\\ % here a new line is expected in the box. 
                second line. \\ \\
            \end{concmath}
        \end{small}\\
    }%
```

error

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\tikz@@align@newline [#1]->\egroup 
                                   \tikz@align@continue \pgfmathparse {#1}\l...
```

is raised. This is reproducible with `tikz` only, when you input multiline node text inside simple environment, as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz \node[align=center] {
  \begin{small}
    first line\\ % here a new line is expected in the box. 
    second line. \\ \\
  \end{small}
};
\end{document}
```

I think this is caused by the redefinition of `\\` inside node text and extra group introduced by simple environment.

Since both `small` and `concmath` environment do font settings, you can move their effect into some font option. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareMathVersion{concmath}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{concmath}{\encodingdefault}{ccr}{m}{n}
\newenvironment{concmath}
  {\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont\mathversion{concmath}}
  {\ignorespaces}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newtcbox{\xtcbox}{
  tikznode,
  fontupper=\small\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont\mathversion{concmath}  
}

\begin{document}
\xtcbox{%
  first line\\ % here a new line is expected in the box. 
  second line. \\ \\
}
\end{document}
```

Moreover, to keep the use of environments `small` and `concmath`, you can nest the box content in a `varwidth` environment, which is defined by `varwidth` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareMathVersion{concmath}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{concmath}{\encodingdefault}{ccr}{m}{n}
\newenvironment{concmath}
  {\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont\mathversion{concmath}}
  {\ignorespaces}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\tcbox{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    \begin{small}
        \begin{concmath}
            first line\\ % here a new line is expected in the box. 
            second line. \\ \\
        \end{concmath}
    \end{small}\\
  \end{varwidth}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works **without** using changing font, but when use of `tikznode` with `concmath` (for changing font) I got an error for the number of `}` ... Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: @Questioner How `concmath` environment is defined? Maybe you should provide a complete example, also called [mwe](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3343).

Comment: I added how to define font change in the question. If you need any complementary information please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Meanwhile, if you know an alternative to `tcbox` that works better for this purpose, please inform me. Thanks

Comment: @Questioner Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use `tcolorbox` instead of `\tcbox`, as follows:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{small}
            \begin{concmath}
                first line\\ % here a new line is expected in the box. 
                second line.
            \end{concmath}
        \end{small}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: `tcolorbox` and `\tcbox` are different in how the width of output box is determined. The width of `tcolorbox` is given. By default the box width is `\linewidth`. The width of `\tcbox` is determined by its content.