# tcbox in Beamer

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying to create a simple colored box with `tcbox` in Beamer. Unfortunately, the following simple example does not work:

```
\documentclass[compress,aspectratio=169,12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{colframe=blue!50!black,
  colback=white,
  colupper=red!50!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,center title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Questions}
  \tcbox{Hello\\ World}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

According to [New line (line breaking) does not work for \tcbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550000/new-line-line-breaking-does-not-work-for-tcbox), I could use `[tikznode]`, and this really solves the problem.

Nevertheless, the documentation states that

```
% Fitted width box (like hbox or makebox)
\tcbox{Hello\\World!}
```

should work (page 14). Also,`\begin{tcolorbox}Hello\\World!\end{tcolorbox}` (also from page 14) works.

Is there some trick to get this working, e.g. using some special `tcbset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `varwidth upper` option:

```
\documentclass[compress,aspectratio=169,12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\tcbset{colframe=blue!50!black,
  colback=white,
  colupper=red!50!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,
  varwidth upper}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Questions}
  \tcbox{Hello\\ World}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem! Could you maybe describe shortly what the reason for the problem is? This would help my understanding of why it happened and also possibly the understanding of future readers.

Comment: @DavidGeorgReichelt I don't think there is a problem, that's juts how `\tcbox` works. The documentation shows that there won't be a line break https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaCoY.png and describes this box to work like a hbox.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Still, my example produces `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` on `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)` - shouldn't this just produce a colorbox without linebreak?

Comment: @DavidGeorgReichelt It works in texlive2022.